# Cannot find main classes set while using jframe in netbean

Tags: java, error-handling, netbeans, reinstall, mainclass

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRU5I.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldWe3.png)
My netbeans main classes cannot been found when I use jframe, but other than jframe, netbeans can function properly, I really dont know what should what should i do to solve it.

I did tried to reinstall the netbeans to solve the problems but it doesn't works.

Comment: Then you don't have a main class. A main class has a method `public static void main(String[] args)` (or with `String...` instead of `String[]`), if it doesn't, it is not a main class. Please provide a [mre].